# Write VHDL code to count frequency of counter clock for MACHX03LF-6900C-CABGA256

Tags: count, reference, clock

I am abit new to VHDL and trying to write a code that count frequency of counter clock.I had counter clock was driven by 12MHz. But I used clock register to slow it down to 45.7Hz by choosing clock register (17).

So what I did was created a reference clock at the same time at higher frequency to accuracy reasons. I used clock register (14) in this case which is 366Hz. I used a reference clock counter as well to say when it is 366HZ which is 1 second. and when it is 137 then reset everything.

I'm not too sure what was wrong with the code in this situation. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

--library MACHXO3;
--use MACHXO3.all;

entity testCC2510 is
    port(clkin: in std_logic;
        reset: in std_logic;
        SW4: in std_logic;
        LED: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        com: out std_logic;
        D2_out: out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
        D1_out: out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
        D0_out: out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
        DP1_out: out std_logic;
        DP2_out: out std_logic;
        LED_out: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));

--  define the pin connections

    attribute loc:string;
    attribute loc of clkin: signal is "C8";
    attribute loc of D0_out: signal is "R13,T14,T12,R11,T11,M11,N10";
    attribute loc of D1_out: signal is "R10,P10,T10,R9,T9,N9,M8";
    attribute loc of D2_out: signal is "M6,L8,T8,P8,R7,R8,T7";
    attribute loc of com: signal is "P7";
    attribute loc of reset: signal is "D2";--was K1
    attribute loc of SW4: signal is "N1";
    attribute loc of DP1_out: signal is "P9";
    attribute loc of DP2_out: signal is "P11";
    attribute loc of LED_out: signal is "F3,D3,G3,C2,F5,E3,B1,C1";
end;


architecture arch_testCC2510 of testCC2510 is

    component SevenSeg
        port(LEDin: in integer;
            SevSegout: out std_logic_vector);
    end component;

    signal ref_clk : std_logic; --reference clk
    signal ref_counter: integer range 0 to 183; -- reference counter
    signal display_0: integer range 0 to 9;
    signal display_1: integer range 0 to 9;

    signal clkreg : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal c_clk: std_logic;
    signal dig2: std_logic_vector(6 downto 0):="1111111";
    signal dig1: std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
    signal dig0: std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
    signal DP1: std_logic:='1';
    signal DP2: std_logic:='1';
    signal count0: integer range 0 to 9;
    signal count1: integer range 0 to 9;
    signal oscpin: std_logic;


begin

    clk1:process(clkin)
        begin
         if (clkin'event and clkin = '1') then          
            clkreg <= clkreg+X"00000001";
        end if;

        ref_clk <= clkreg (14);
        c_clk <= clkreg(17);
        oscpin <= clkreg(15);

    end process clk1;

--LCD modulation to avoid damage to LCD screen
    lcdmod:process(oscpin)
        begin
         if (oscpin='1') then
            D2_out<=dig2;
            D1_out<=dig1;
            D0_out<=dig0;
            DP1_out<=DP1;
            DP2_out<=DP2;
         else
            D2_out<= not dig2;
            D1_out<= not dig1;
            D0_out<= not dig0;
            DP1_out<= not DP1;
            DP2_out<= not DP2;
         end if;
            com<=oscpin;

    end process;

    DD0:SevenSeg port map(display_0,dig0);
    DD1:SevenSeg port map(display_1,dig1);



    p_counter: process 
    begin
        wait until rising_edge(c_clk);

        if (SW4='1') then
            if (((count1=9) and (count0=9)) or reset='0') then
                count1<=0;
                count0<=0;
            elsif(count0=9) then
                count1<=count1+1;
                count0<=0;
            else
                count0<=count0+1;
            end if;

        end if;

--          
        end process p_counter;

    Ref_cnt: process (ref_clk)

    begin

    wait until rising_edge (ref_clk);

    if (ref_clk = 366) then

    display_0 <= count0;
    display_1 <= count1;

    elseif (ref_clk = 367) then --reset count0 and count1

    count0 <= 0;
    count1 <= 0;
    ref_count <= 0;

    else
    ref_clk = ref_clk + 1;

    end if;

    end process Ref_cnt;


        LED_out <= "00000000";

end arch_testCC2510;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity SevenSeg is
    port(LEDin: integer range 0 to 9;
        SevSegout: out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0));
end;
architecture SevenSeg_arch of SevenSeg is
begin
    process(LEDin)
    begin
        Lab0:case LEDin is
            when 0=>SevSegout<="0000001";
            when 1=>SevSegout<="1001111";
            when 2=>SevSegout<="0010010";
            when 3=>SevSegout<="0000110";
            when 4=>SevSegout<="1001100";
            when 5=>SevSegout<="0100100";
            when 6=>SevSegout<="0100000";
            when 7=>SevSegout<="0001111";
            when 8=>SevSegout<="0000000";
            when 9=>SevSegout<="0000100";
        end case Lab0;
    end process;
end SevenSeg_arch;
```

Comment: I know VHDL is verbose, but this example lacks clarity. Some comments would be useful, as for example, which does this module exatly do (to count pulses, you output a binary value, but this seems to output already decoded seven segment values. I'd suggest moving that to another module and instead, focus on your specific problem. SW4 doesn't seem like a clock input, but a switch. If you are planning to count keypresses in your trainer, I'd suggest also to add a debouncer, or you will end counting many more pulses than you actually made.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. please ignore the SW4 in this case. it was trying to make the code count up and count down before. I don't want to count key presses though. 

The reason I decoded seven segment so everytime the reference clock counts to 366 I know its one second so I should display the value of frequency of counter clock. In other words, count0 is unit count, and count1 is tens count. so say when counter clk counts to 45 and reference clock is 366 then display 45 on LCD screen. Hope its clear. I just don't know what the mistake is in my code.